# ListView of images not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to customize ListView to show a list of images so i wrote the following code but unfortunately its not working.

**layout/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/menu_bg">
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/name"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/menu_list"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="60sp"></ListView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**layout/menu_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Menu.java**

```
public class Menu extends Activity{


private int[] items = {R.drawable.res_opt, R.drawable.new_game_opt, R.drawable.score_opt, R.drawable.exit_opt};
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
    list.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(Menu.this, items));
 }
}
```

**MenuAdapter.java**

```
 public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

private int[] items;
private Context context;

public MenuAdapter(Context context, int[] items) {
    super(context, R.layout.menu_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //make sure we have a view to work with
    View itemView = convertView;
    if(itemView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item,null, true);
    }
        //Find the object to work with
        int id = items[position];

        //Fill the view
        ImageView item = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        item.setImageResource(id);

    return itemView;

 }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with "itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, true);" ?

Comment: override getCount() and return your array size in it.

Comment: yup 1st i tried that @Vink

Answer (score 0):

Add view holder class to your code, as its incomplete.

```
    public class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView iv;
    }
```

Now, your code will look like this:

```
ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
if(itemView == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item,null, null);
    mViewHolder.iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    itemView.setTag(mViewHolder);
}else{
    mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
}
//Find the object to work with
int id = items[position];
//Fill the view
mViewHolder.iv.setImageResource(id);
```

Also, you have missed adding size for you ListView adapter.

Hope, this could help you.

Comment: the result is still same

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another super constuctor of ArrayAdapter.

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>{

private Integer[] items;
private Context context;

public MenuAdapter(Context context, Integer[] items) {
    super(context, R.layout.menu_item, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}
```

**Edited**

Also fix this line

```
itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item,parent, false);
```

Comment: by adding items it says "cannot resolve method super(android.context.Context, int , int[])"

Comment: @IqraRana Fixed my answer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html ArrayAdapter is a generic class, and you need to define it`s type.

Comment: @IqraRana check out eidted answer